# Why does SiteLocalization.getLanguage() return null

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

I've been looking at the methods on the SiteLocalization class in DXA. I'd like to get the language of each site but getLanguage() returns null. This doesn't surprise me much, because I haven't configured the language anywhere. How can I use this feature?

Comment: Are you looking for this confguration?
 https://docs.sdl.com/784837/704733/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/configuring-the-web-application-for-multilingual-websites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Language inside the `Localization` object is populated from the following Component:

```
\DXA 100 Master\Building Blocks\Settings\Core\Site Manager\Localization
```

Once set, do a Republish Settings + Admin/Refresh (or restart the app).